# Add styles to body when hovering a div on the page

Tags: css

I know I can prevent a page from scrolling using:

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But I need these styles to be applied when the user is hovering over a `div` on my page.

Is there a way to apply styles to the body like this - from inside a hover?

Comment: I would guess this can only be achieved with JS/jQuery

Comment: Related: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/419956)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to style a parent with CSS, but you can use javascript. Note I've added a line for the background color to simulate the effect, this can be removed for your purposes.

```js
document.getElementById("hover").onmouseover = function() {
  // on hover set the body to position fixed and overflow hidden
  document.body.style.position = "fixed";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,75,250,0.5)";
}
document.getElementById("hover").onmouseout = function() {
  // when the user is done hovering, reset
  document.body.style.position = "";
  document.body.style.overflow = "";
  document.body.style.background = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="hover">Hover over me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (done with jQuery):

```
<div>Test</div>

$('div').hover(function() {
    $('body').attr('position','fixed');
    $('body').attr('overflow','hidden');
});
```

Comment: not for the ones that use jQuery in nearly each and every project ;-)

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 Agreed. Unless OP is already using jQuery, Javascript is enough for this.

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi Using jQuery for each and every project is a bad habit (which I admit being guilty of myself). jQuery is a very powerful plugin, but this also means that it adds a lot of extra load to your website. For small things, jQuery often is just overkill and Javascript would be a lot better performance-wise. That said, your answer is not bad. It can definitely be useful for future visitors which *are* using jQuery anyway. I'd just want to avoid recommending jQuery for everything to newbies.

Comment: believe me: we are not building kiddy apps.... we are building european web pages and it's helpful and needful to use jQuery in most of the projects. This is why I said: we use it nearly each and every time

Comment: @humble.rumble: he also did say nothing about using Javascript... so this is a stupid comment